# QTP 9.2 Not recognising Uniface screens

Tags: qtp

I am using QTP 9.2 , where i would like to automate Uniface and delphi screens.I tried it by different object recognition methods but Uniface screen is not According to it.Where a dialog box appears in which if i click ok i can proceed to the next step.But dialog box is not appearing for a long time and QTP tires and stops the process.I tried using Analog recording mode but it did not allow me to enter in the uniface screen and the whole desktop gets stuck.I would like to know is ADDin required or can we do directly.I would request if there is any idea...

Answer (score 0):

It is probably connected to the way Uniface handles screen furniture.  Each editbox has its own handle.  I'm not familiar with quick test pro but I have similar issues with other testing suites.

Comment: I tried with several of the screens. But seems only with qtp 10 having delphi addin it works...

Answer (score 0):

UNIFACE uses standard Windows controls and they can be recognized by most testing tools. We use TestPartner and RanoRex. Exceptions are the grid and the unifield. The standard controls are equiped with an MSAA interface by MS so this is pretty straight forward.

Hope this helps
Jasper